# Option redefinition in kconfig

Tags: cmake, makefile, сборка

Правильная модель поведения при попытке переопределения опции в kconfig?

В нашем проекте общая часть кода для генерации конфигурационных файлов вынесена в общие файлы. (Для препроцессинга используем [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp)).

Псевдо пример описания пакета (после GPP):

```
config components_1
    bool "arm"
    depends on TARGET_ARM_OS
    default y

config components_1
    bool
    depends on TARGET_ARM_OS
    select another_components_1
    default y

config components_1
    bool
    depends on TARGET_ARM_OS
    select another_components_2
    default y
```

При проcмотре и редактировании [меню](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menuconfig) мы видим, что при включенной платформе ARM и требуемой ОС к сборке подключились обе зависимости another_components_1 и another_components_2.

Так ли это должно быть?

Не должно ли быть переопределения? В [документации](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/kconfig-language.html) не нашёл ответа на этот вопрос.

Comment: не совсем понятно, в чём суть вопроса? и почему в примере 3 одинаковых `config`'а?

Comment: Суть вопроса: Должно ли было произойти слияние конфигураций или переопределение с помощью последней?

Comment: мм... тогда хз... всё о чём можно было бы сказать ты уже описал в вопросе: в доке ничего конкретного нет (хотя не то чтобы kconfig досконально доокументирован), по факту — происходит «слияние»... с другой стороны для `depends` написано, что оно объединяет через `&&`; так что вряд ли можно ожидать, что это баг... но если есть возможность, то я бы старался избегать подобного...

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `merge_config` из Yocto. Это мощный инструмент по собиранию *Kconfig* из кусочков. Он автоматически добавляет все необходимые зависимости.

Comment: Спасибо, попробуем посмотреть.